# No OCRs created from lead conversion in unit tests

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, lead-conversion, opportunitycontactrole

I need to write code that ensures only one opportunity is marked as active (using a custom field called `Active__c`) for a given contact. The code needs to run in an after update lead trigger after conversion that relies on an OCR record existing between the converted contact and the converted opportunity. The unit test fails, however, and when I queried the OCR to make sure it existed, I was surprised to see that it didn't.

I found a few other answers on here saying that OCRs have to be created manually in test classes, but that fails to simulate an actual conversion event through the UI (where OCRs are created ***during*** the conversion process rather than ***after***). How can I reliably test this code in the context of a test class?

**Test class**

```
@isTest
private class LeadTriggerTest {

    static testMethod void testActiveFlagWithExistingActiveOpportunity() {
        // Insert first lead
        Lead firstLead = new Lead();
        firstLead.LastName = 'Last';
        insert firstLead;

        // Convert first lead
        Database.LeadConvert converter = new Database.LeadConvert();
        converter.setLeadId(firstLead.Id);
        converter.setConvertedStatus('Applied');
        Database.LeadConvertResult result = Database.convertLead(converter);
        Id convertedAccountId = result.getAccountId();
        Id convertedContactId = result.getContactId();
        Id convertedOpportunityId = result.getOpportunityId();

        // Insert second lead
        Lead secondLead = new Lead();
        secondLead.LastName = 'Last';
        insert secondLead;

        // Convert second lead into first contact
        Test.startTest();
        converter = new Database.LeadConvert();
        converter.setLeadId(secondLead.Id);
        converter.setAccountId(convertedAccountId);
        converter.setContactId(convertedContactId);
        converter.setConvertedStatus('Applied');
        result = Database.convertLead(converter);
        Test.stopTest();

        // Select opportunities from conversion
        Opportunity firstOpp = [SELECT Active__c FROM Opporunity WHERE Id = :convertedOpportunityId];
        Opportunity secondOpp = [SELECT Active__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :result.getOpportunityId()];

        // Test that active flags were set correctly
        System.assertEquals(false, firstOpp.Active__c);
        System.assertEquals(true, firstOpp.Active__c);
    }

}
```

**Lead trigger**

```
trigger Lead on Lead (after update) {

    if (Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {

        // Get contact and opportunity IDs for leads that were just converted
        List<Id> convertedContactIds = new List<Id>();
        List<Id> convertedOppIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {
            Lead newLead = l;
            Lead oldLead = Trigger.oldMap.get(l.Id);
            if (newLead.IsConverted && !oldLead.IsConverted && newLead.ConvertedOpportunityId != null) {
                convertedContactIds.add(newLead.ConvertedContactId);
                convertedOppIds.add(newLead.ConvertedOpportunityId);
            }
        }

        // Query all opps for converted contacts that are NOT in this set of converted opportunities
        List<OpportunityContactRole> oppRoles = [SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE ContactId IN :convertedContactIds AND OpportunityId NOT IN :convertedOppIds AND Opportunity.Active__c = true];

        // Set Active__c flag to false for found opportunities and update
        List<Opportunity> oppsToDeactivate = new List<Opportunity>();
        for (OpportunityContactRole r : oppRoles) {
            Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
            opp.Id = r.OpportunityId;
            opp.Active__c = false;
            oppsToDeactivate.add(opp);
        }

        update oppsToDeactivate;
    }

}
```

Comment: Put your code to be tested and corresponding test class.

Comment: @Reshma Code added.